# header with a position fixed attribute responds to offset given to content

Tags: html, css

Within my `body` tag I have a `header` and `div#content` element. My aim was to create a fixed header and then push the `content` of the `content` element out from under it using a `margin-top` attribute. However when I did this the `header` also moved down as though it were joined to the `content`. I fixed this by adding a `position: absolute` to the `content`. The trouble is I cant explain to myself why it worked. It just did. I am using Firefox on Ubuntu.

This is the `header` css:

```
header {
position: fixed;
top: 0px,
left: 0px;
margin: 0px;
background-color: #3F51B5;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF; 
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
```

}

This is the `content` css:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
```

}

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKXLXX).

Please educate me someone :)

Comment: Also use overflow: hidden; at your ul#menu cause you used float at li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several observations:

- `position: absolute;` didn't **really** fix it. Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWKdvZ) for a demonstration. Notice the fair amount of content I added after your `div`s and how they don't display correctly? This is because:
- You had a typo on your first css element. Here's a codepen demonstrating a fix: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwvBJy You wrote `,` instead of `;`. You didn't close the `top: ;` attribute so your browser tried to fix it by using the `#content` `margin-top`.

Comment: good job, the more irritating bugs often seem to be the most simplest to solve. I will see if I can find a css linter for subime

Answer (score 1):

Bad syntax-- used a `,` instead of `;` on line 3

```
header {
position: fixed;
top: 0px,
left: 0px;
```

so the attributes `top` and `left` are wrecked.

Answer (score 1):

You used a comma instead of a semicolon here

## head { top 0px }

Please replace the comma with smemicolon than you dont need position: absolute .